Function closure objects are not created when emacs load files in lexical evironment specified in .emacs init file at startup as emacsclient
I started to use lexical environment to my Emacs 27.1 files on i3 in Ubuntu .
I wrote ;; -*- lexical-binding: t; -*- the first line of the gheg-dired-mode.el and and start Emacs server with:
exec x-terminal-emulator -e emacs --daemon
and Emacs client with:
bindsym $mod+y exec x-terminal-emulator -e emacsclient -nw
I start command:
M-: (symbol-function 'gheg-dired-reset-paths)
in gheg-dired-mode.el buffer to see the object stacked at symbol's function cell, in order to find out if the closure objects has already created.
gheg-dired-reset-paths is an ordinary function in gheg-dired-mode.el
(defun gheg-dired-reset-path ()
"Reset gheg-clip-path-list variable to nil"
(setq gheg-clip-path-list nil))

The result is:
#[0 "A\211^P\207" [gheg-clip-path-list nil] 2 ("/home/ghegheg/Programare-25.04.24/Portofolio/gheg-dired-mode.elc" . 2650) nil]
I don't know to read this result, but certainly it's not a closure that is a list that starts with closure word.
I decide to load gheg-dired-mode.el manually
M-x load-file gheg-dired-mode.el

to see what happens, and resume the command
M-: (symbol-function 'gheg-dired-reset-paths)
Now the result is:
(closure (t) nil "Reset gheg-clip-path-list variable to nil" (interactive) (setq gheg-clip-path-list nil))

so the closure was created.
I mentions the gheg-dired-mode.el file was specified in .emacs init file with (require 'gheg-dired-mode) declaration, so emacs loads needed files but it not creates closures at files where ;; -*- lexical-binding: t; -*- is present on the first line of file. This strange things happened to other functions and files, not only one function and file.
I deleted correspondent .elc files and recreated again with byte-compile files, but after ubuntu restart the result is the same.
Can somebody to explain me what happened? Why are the closure not created at Emacs startup?


I don't know to read this result, but certainly it's not a closure

This is an incorrect assumption.  (Or at minimum, what you're looking at is entirely equivalent to what you were looking for.)

that is a list that starts with closure word.

You're comparing byte-compiled code with uncompiled code.
If you test (with code where it would make a difference) you'll be able to confirm that lexical binding is in effect in your byte-compiled code.
The byte-code function might not be considered a "closure" per-se, as all of the relevant values in the lexical environment will have been embedded into the byte-code by that point.
FYI the number at the start of the byte-code object #[0 ...] confirms that the function was defined under lexical binding, just as the closure at the start of the uncompiled form confirms it.  If dynamic binding was in effect, there would be a list (maybe nil) in that position.  If you want to dig into the details, there's a great reference at https://github.com/rocky/elisp-bytecode
As a simple demonstration, under dynamic binding:
(eval '(byte-compile (let ((foo 'bar)) (lambda () foo))))
#[nil "^H\207" [foo] 1]

Whereas compiling under lexical binding:
(eval '(byte-compile (let ((foo 'bar)) (lambda () foo))) t)
#[0 "\300\207" [bar] 1]

Which, even if you can't read it, clearly demonstrates the effect of the lexical closure on the compiled code.
More readably, if we C-h f disassemble those objects we get these respective results:
byte code:
  args: nil
0   varref    foo
1   return    

byte code:
  args: nil
0   constant  bar
1   return    

